# import additional scss as theme on demand in angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am implementing admin panel for my application and the same has been lazy loaded, but I would like to speparate scss for admin panel. Say:

Public Portal
ecom-blue.scss

Admin Panel:
ecom-blue.scss
ecom-admin.scss

As of now I am importing both the CSSs in theme.scss like this way:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
@import "themes/ecom-blue";
@import 'themes/ecom-admin';
$background: map-get($ecom-theme, background);
$foreground: map-get($ecom-theme, foreground);
```

which is further imported in app.scss this way:

```
@import "scss/variables";
@import "scss/themes";
@import "scss/views";
```

In angular.json

```
"styles": ["src/assets/styles/app.scss",
"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"]
```

The problem with this approach is that the style.css (compiled file) will be having both the themes whereas I just want rent of the css to be included where my admin router layout is activated as per lazy loading.

may I know the best approach for this so that style.css file should be divided as per module and also to be loaded when required.

Edit:
This is how my router component look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-layout',
  templateUrl: './auth-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../admin-layout.scss'],
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and this is how it is lazy loaded:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin4556',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
        data: { title: 'Admin', breadcrumb: 'Admin'}
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: If you will use `ViewEncapsulation.None`, yes, this allows you to apply base styles for children components, for example, if you style tag `<p>` in the parent component, the same style for `<p>` will be applied in the children component. BUT this is not the best practice. So if you sometimes will want to change your style in the child you need to add `!important` or add more points to your element to make it more specific. Will be better if you move out all common styles to BaseTheme or even styles.scss, and leave some specific styles inside lazy-loaded components. `''` helps if you want to split your routes by different style areas if you have only one area base style you can go with styles.css only.

ORIGINAL:
If you want to apply some common style, for example, to user and admin components, and at the same time have some styles lazy-loaded specifically to each of them, you can do it with `''` route. This is not some specific route, it's just skipped and goes further to children, but this allows us to add additional styles before it. It looks like this:

```
 {
   path: '',
   component: BaseTheme, //base style
   children: [
      { path: 'adminpanel', loadChildren: () => import('./adminpanel/adminpanel.module').then(m => m.AdminPanelModule) } //inside we add specific style
      { path: 'userpanel', loadChildren: () => import('./userpanel/userpanel.module').then(m => m.UserPanelModule) } //inside we add specific style
    ]
  }
```

Comment: if I load certain scss on CommonUserLayoutComponent load it will be available for that component only. like styleUrls: ['./../admin-layout.scss'].  .... can you show me any example how should I import it for the entire set of components under that router outlet component

Comment: @Jay Hope, I understood you correctly, take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: You mean to say instead of component I add my additional css to there component: BaseTheme, //base style Then where should I mention my component? Right now I am doing this:

Comment: {
    path: '',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin4556',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
        data: { title: 'Admin', breadcrumb: 'Admin'}
      }
    ]
  },

Comment: I edited my question for your understanding what already is done.

Comment: great!  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None works well to load style. Previsouly, it was throwing error on NgModule Import so I commented it. Uncommenting the same is working.

Comment: I am looking for an elaborative answer clearing everything so that I may mark it as answer and help others in the same situation. thanks.